# Download and Install 32-bit Haskell GHC on CentOS

Tags: centos, libraries, 32bit, haskell

I need to install Haskell GHC 32 bit from the command line and I can't find this anywhere.

I need to install it because I need `libgmp.so.3` for the 32-bit and i have read somewhere that I can find it when I install the Haskell GHC.

Any ideas how can I install it?

Comment: Were you running a 64bit os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libgmp.so.3` doesn't have anything to do with Haskell. It belongs to the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/), which in CentOS should be available in the package `gmp` (or similar, I don't have a CentOS box to test right now).

Comment: well it seems i am searching in a wrong place. do you have any idea how to install from the command line on CentOS ?

Comment: try `yum install gmp`

Comment: i did that and i got that back. Package gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
which is the 64 version if i am not mistaken ??

Answer (score 2):

try

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s libgmp.so.3 libgmp.so
```